# Determining general form of sets for set builder notation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

I am working through these problems in Hammack's Book of Proof. While I have minimal issues finding the elements of sets when they are listed in set notation such as $$\{3x+2:x\in\mathbb{Z}\}$$, I struggle to determine the general form of the sequence.  Are there any general formulae or strategies that can be used to determine these sequences?

For context, I am able to determine sequences like #23 to be $\{x\in\mathbb{N}:3\leq x \leq 8\}$, but struggle with some others that may be "less obvious".

[image: these problems from Hammack]

Comment: I don't think there are any general strategies other than recognising patterns.

Comment: Here is a fun strategy: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NO1_-qptr6c

Comment: Putting elements of a sequence in [wolframalpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com) or in [OEIS](https://oeis.org) will often yield a closed form.